# Selecting DOM elements with inAppBrowser - Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

It seems I can't select DOM elements from a website I've loaded using the inAppBrowser plugin. When I log `document.getElementById("input")` it's `null`. The resources I've read on this have treated selecting elements as trivial, but I seem unable.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var obj = {
      link: "https://www.foolink.com",
      input: "barInput",
      func: function(obj) {
          document.getElementById("input").value = obj.input;
      }
}

var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(obj.link, "_blank");
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {

  ref.executeScript({code:obj.func(obj)})

})
```

Has anyone else encountered this before? Using jquery to get selectors on gives me selectors from the index.html file, not the inAppBrowser window.

*edit: currently using inAppBrowser 1.4.0 and cordova 6.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frix33 got the gears turning with his answer, but I don't think it specifically identifies the problem so posting my own. The script injected into the page must be a STRING or else it is just executed by the app, which is a different `document` hence the `null` result before. It works if you replace `{code: obj.func(obj)}` with:

```
var codePass = "document.getElementById('input').value = '"+ obj.input +"';"
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(obj.link, "_blank", "location=yes");
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {

   ref.executeScript({code:codePass})

});
```

You can pass as many script lines as needed using that format.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me (cordova 6.1.1, inappbrowser 1.4.0, platform Android):

```
...
            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function () {

            ref.executeScript(
                { code: "document.getElementById('inputID')" },
                function (values) {
                    alert(values[0]);
                }
            );

...
```